# whether std::future::wait_for uses different clock(steady clock vs system clock) depends on compiler?

Tags: c++, gcc, std-future

When I use different compilers to compile following code,

```
auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){return myfunction();});

auto status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
if (status == std::future_status::ready)
{
    auto result = future.get();
    std::cout << "result is " << result << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << (status == std::future_status::timeout ? "timeout" : "deferred") << std::endl;
}
```

When `wait_for` function is waiting for `myfunction` to be finished (wait for duration is 5000 milliseconds), I set the system clock ahead by one minute.

- With gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC), `future::wait_for` returned timeout soon
- With gcc version 13.2.0 (GCC), `future::wait_for` is still waiting

It seems `future::wait_for` has different behaviors with different compilers.

According to [wait_for](https://docs.w3cub.com/cpp/thread/future/wait_for), *The standard recommends that a steady clock is used to measure the duration. If an implementation uses a system clock instead, the wait time may also be sensitive to clock adjustments.*

It looks like gcc version 10.2.0 uses system clock for `future::wait_for`, and gcc version 13.2.0 uses steady clock for `future::wait_for`.

Does this mean compiler will use a steady clock or a system clock?

Is there any compile flag to specify whether to use a steady clock or a system clock?

Comment: The docs you quote is already the answer to your first question: It might be a steady clock or it might be the system clock. When it is the system clock the wait time may be sensitive to clock adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean compiler will use a steady clock or a system clock?

Yes.

> Is there any compile flag to specify whether to use a steady clock or a system clock?

No. I am not aware of such flag.

---

`std::future` has certain issues (mainly related to being the return type of `std::async`. It was even considered for deprecation if I remember correctly. todo: add reference). This seems to be another one.

Note that [`std::future::wait_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_until) does allow you to choose the Clock to use. This difference might be just due to the fact that the Clock is part of the `time_point`s type but not of a `duration` (the argument to `wait_for`). However, you can calculate the `time_point` from a `duration` for a Clock of your choice and use that with `wait_until` to wait for the result.

Comment: Many thanks for your clarification @463035818_is_not_an_ai.