# What is the default clock type of std::chrono::duration?

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono

I've seen that there are 2 different clock types, `steady_clock` (monotonic clock) and `system_clock` (wall clock). If I use `std::chrono::duration` to wait some time, e.g.:

```
cv.wait_for( lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
```

So what's the default clock type of `std::chrono::milliseconds(10000)`? If I want to sleep for 10s, and the computer os has slept very long time after wait for 2s, after the OS awake, would it continue sleep for another 8s or end sleep?

Comment: duration has no clock type. The clock which you use to measure the duration has a clock type. So, ask the condition variable what clock it uses.

Comment: if you want to choose the clock you can use `wait_until`, because time points depend on a clock, durations dont

Comment: `std::chrono::miliseconds` is a duration and does not use a clock, `wait_for` uses a clock. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for): *The standard recommends that a steady clock be used to measure the duration. This function may block for longer than timeout_duration due to scheduling or resource contention delays.*

Comment: related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77272536/4117728

Comment: If I were to put your question into non-technical terms, you are asking something similar to *"In what time zone is the 10 seconds measured?"* (Does time zone/clock affect how long a duration is?) The last question is similar to *"If I tell someone to do something in 10 hours, and that person falls asleep 2 hours later, will that person count the time spent asleep as part of the 10 hours?"* (Doesn't this sound like a question about the person rather than about the time duration?)

Comment: @JaMiT I dont think its that obvious. 10 seconds measured in a time zone with a leap second can be different. Its convention to take durations as absolute, in your case you assume the "persons clock" to be without leaps without skipping or missing some minutes, but what makes the "person clock" more special than other clocks?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai *"10 seconds measured in a time zone with a leap second can be different"* -- No, it cannot. The difference between two times can depend on a leap second occurring, but "10 seconds" is "10 seconds" independent of what the wall clock says at the start and end of the duration. It might be that 10 seconds after 11:59:55 is 12:00:04 instead of 12:00:05 because of a leap second, but that does not change how much time had passed.

Answer (score 4):

Clocks are not associated with `duration` in any way.  However, if you go to the definition of `condition_variable::wait_for` you can see that [the answer to your question in this case is `steady_clock`.](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.condition.condvar#24)

And in general, you'll have to look somewhere besides `duration` to find out if a "default clock" is in effect.

For `sleep_for`, it looks more promising than it is.  The requirements are not spelled out [at the definition of `sleep_for`](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.this#7), but you are referred to [[thread.req.timing]](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.timing).

[Here it says:](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.timing#3.sentence-3)

> The functions whose names end in `_for` take an argument that specifies a duration. These functions produce relative timeouts. Implementations should use a steady clock to measure time for these functions.

- "a steady clock" does not mean `steady_clock`.  It means a clock for which [the nested value `is_steady`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.req#tab:time.clock-row-6) is `true`.
- ["should" doesn't mean "shall".](https://tyndaleusa.com/blog/2023/05/12/decoding-the-language-of-standards-should-vs-shall/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CShould%E2%80%9D%20is%20also%20defined%20in,6.4.) "Should" means that implementations are encouraged to do it, but not required to do it.   "Shall" means implementations do it, or are not conforming to the standard.

So `sleep_for` doesn't have a "default clock".

On how long a thread might "sleep" or "wait":  The short answer is that it will sleep or wait for at least as long as the argument says it will.  And it may sleep/wait longer.  How much longer?  As long as it wants to.

The longer answer is in [[thread.req.timing]](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.timing).